# Does SSL_CTX_use_certificate copy used certificate bytes?

Tags: c++, openssl

Does function `SSL_CTX_use_certificate` copy a certificate bytes?
Can I free the certificate memory by call `X509_free(cert);` after the function call?

```
    BIO *cbio = BIO_new_mem_buf((void*)cert_iter, first_cert_length);
    X509 *cert = PEM_read_bio_X509(cbio, NULL, 0, NULL);
    BIO_free(cbio);
    assert(cert != NULL);
    SSL_CTX_use_certificate(mSslServerRoleCtx.native_handle(), cert);
```

Comment: From the manpage: "The SSL_CTX_* class of functions loads the certificates and keys into the SSL_CTX object ctx. The information is passed to SSL objects ssl created from ctx with SSL_new by copying, so that changes applied to ctx do not propagate to already existing SSL objects." I'm not familiar with OpenSSL, but maybe you can make more sense of these words?

Comment: Yes, "The information is passed to SSL objects ssl created from ctx with SSL_new by copying, so that changes applied to ctx" is quite promising. But I read this before posting on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [OpenSSL on GitHub](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/ssl/ssl_rsa.c) function `ssl_set_cert` uses `X509_up_ref` on the certificate. So I assume I can call `X509_free(cert);`